# Openweathemap API saying temperature is like 282

Tags: python, python-requests, openweathermap

So I've made a program in python that tells you the weather and I'm using OpenWeatherMap API to do so.

Expect when I GET the information the temperature is like really off? I thought it was an API but I doubt it.

```
{"coord":{"lon":-0.13,"lat":51.51},"weather":[{"id":501,"main":"Rain","description":"moderate rain","icon":"10d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":282.48,"feels_like":277.86,"temp_min":282.04,"temp_max":283.15,"pressure":981,"humidity":87},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":5.7,"deg":240},"rain":{"1h":1.15},"clouds":{"all":100},"dt":1601797507,"sys":{"type":1,"id":1414,"country":"GB","sunrise":1601791589,"sunset":1601832694},"timezone":3600,"id":2643743,"name":"London","cod":200}
```

I want the temperature in Celsius, but I don't understand how to get it?

Here's my code:

```
weathercity = input("What city are you in? ")
weather = requests.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='+weathercity+'&appid=...')
url = ('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='+weathercity+'&appid=...')



data = weather.json()

temp = data['main']['temp']
description = data['weather'][0]['description']
weatherprint ="In {}, it is currently {}° with {}."
spinner = spinning_cursor()
for _ in range(25):
    sys.stdout.write(next(spinner))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    sys.stdout.write('\b')
print(weatherprint.format(weathercity, temp, description))
```

Comment: Not looked at the docs but that's almost certainly temperature in the Kelvin scale. Subtract 273.15 to get Celsius. This isn't a python problem

Comment: From the doc: "main.temp Temperature. Unit Default: Kelvin".

Comment: Yeah Iknew it wasn't python but I din't where the api got the number from / I didn't know the scale.
Also thanks

Comment: Also don't share your private API key ( no matter the website) on public space, it could impersonnate you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://openweathermap.org/current#parameter) states the default temperature unit is `Kelvin`.  To get [celsius unit](https://openweathermap.org/current#data) use `units=metric`

Also to get it proper I'd suggest to use the `params` parameter to pass out URL args

```
APP_ID = "..."
url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather'
weather = requests.get(url, params={'units': 'metric',
                                    'appid': APP_ID,
                                    'q': weathercity})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
import time
import sys

weathercity = input("What city are you in? ")
weather = requests.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='+weathercity+'&appid=886705b4c1182eb1c69f28eb8c520e20')
url = ('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='+weathercity+'&appid=886705b4c1182eb1c69f28eb8c520e20')




def spinning_cursor():
    while True:
        for cursor in '|/-\\':
            yield cursor


data = weather.json()

temp = data['main']['temp']
description = data['weather'][0]['description']
weatherprint ="In {}, it is currently {}°C with {}."
spinner = spinning_cursor()
for _ in range(25):
    sys.stdout.write(next(spinner))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    sys.stdout.write('\b')

convert = int(temp - 273.15)
print(weatherprint.format(weathercity, convert, description))
```

Comment: Here is our solution

Comment: Do you wanna join me. I have a group of coders. i am 12 yrs old

Comment: no thanks I'm proabbly to old to join your group, btw you sholud 13 to use this site...
thanks for your answer tho, there was an option in the api to change it